# Ошибка: "too many values to unpack (expected 4)"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, словари, dict

пытаюсь добавить в DataFrame столбцы на по ключу на основании справочника по клиентам:

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame((['A105', 'A115', 'A120', 'A130', 'A170']), columns= 
['APO_L2'])

client2 = {}
client2['A105'] = ['A1', 'СЕТИ', 'A105', 'Окей']
client2['A115'] = ['A1', 'СЕТИ', 'A115', 'Лента']
client2['A120'] = ['A1', 'СЕТИ', 'A120', 'Призма']
client2['A130'] = ['A1', 'СЕТИ', 'A130', 'Х5']
client2['A130'] = ['A1', 'СЕТИ', 'A130', 'Тандер']
client2['A170'] = ['A1', 'СЕТИ', 'A130', 'Ашан']


df2['APO_L1'], df2['QV_L1'], df2['APO_L2'], df2['QV_L2'] = 
df2['APO_L2'].map(lambda x: client2[x])
```

в результате ожидаю получить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но вылезает ошибка:

too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Добавляю 4 столбца, словарь по значению также выдает список из 4 значений. Что не так?

Comment: приведите в вопросе датасет который вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: добавил. Спасибо!

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) в данном случае использовать нецелесообразно, т.к. данный метод возвращает `Series` (столбец), а вы пытаетесь добавить сразу четыре столбца.

```
In [33]: df2['APO_L2'].map(lambda x: client2[x])
Out[33]:
0      [A1, СЕТИ, A105, Окей]
1     [A1, СЕТИ, A115, Лента]
2    [A1, СЕТИ, A120, Призма]
3    [A1, СЕТИ, A130, Тандер]
4      [A1, СЕТИ, A130, Ашан]
Name: APO_L2, dtype: object
```

Здесь вы получили единственный столбец (`Series`), со списками в качестве элементов. При попытке присвоить значения данного единственного столбца четырем новым столбцам вы предсказуемо получаете ошибку `"ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)"`

Т.е. метод `.map()` удобно использовать для замены значений (`mapping`) в *единственном* столбце.

Если вам надо добавить несколько столбцов, то для этого существуют методы [.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) и [.join()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

[Документация с примерами по объединению данных в Pandas...](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html)

---

Со справочником будет удобнее работать если он будет представлен в виде DataFrame:

```
In [14]: info = pd.DataFrame(client2, index='APO_L1 QV_L1 APO_L2 QV_L2'.split()).T

In [15]: info
Out[15]:
     APO_L1 QV_L1 APO_L2   QV_L2
A105     A1  СЕТИ   A105    Окей
A115     A1  СЕТИ   A115   Лента
A120     A1  СЕТИ   A120  Призма
A130     A1  СЕТИ   A130  Тандер
A170     A1  СЕТИ   A130    Ашан

In [27]: res = df2.merge(info, how='left')

In [28]: res
Out[28]:
  APO_L2 index APO_L1 QV_L1   QV_L2
0   A105  A105     A1  СЕТИ    Окей
1   A115  A115     A1  СЕТИ   Лента
2   A120  A120     A1  СЕТИ  Призма
3   A130  A130     A1  СЕТИ  Тандер
4   A130  A170     A1  СЕТИ    Ашан
```

Comment: Проблема merge в том, что если в справочнике не будет какого-то ключа, то основной dataframe просто пропустит сроку. Другими словами будет потеря данных. Как подстараховаться?

Comment: @Timur, для этого надо использовать параметр: `how='left'` - дополнил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! работает.

Может подскажите еще, как заранее перехватить ключ, которого нет в словаре, т.е. как понять, обратить свое внимание что такого-то ключа нет в справочнике. Как вывести print по недостающим данным.